# jQuery .eq() for multiple instances?

Tags: jquery

I have the following which is working fine:

```
if (jQuery('#target').val() == '1') {
    jQuery('.room_row').addClass('hide').eq(0).removeClass("hide");
  }
```

However I need to add something like this so that the first 2 div.room_row's have their 'hide' class removed:

```
if (jQuery('#target').val() == '2') {
    jQuery('.room_row').addClass('hide').eq(0,1).removeClass("hide");
  }
```

UPDATE A lot of people are recommending using slice but I cant get it to work. I have 7 divs with a class of room_row. When you select the option 1 in the select list I need the first .room_row to be visible. If you select 2 I need the first 2 .room_row to be visible, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
jQuery('.room_row').addClass('hide').slice(0,2).removeClass('hide');
```

Also this would be helpful to you

```
    jQuery('.room_row:gt(2)').addClass('hide');
```

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing:

```
jQuery('.room_row').slice(2).addClass("hide");
```

Here's a simple example:

```
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].slice(2)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].slice(0, 2)
[1, 2]
```

Alternatively, there's `:lt` and `:gt`:

```
jQuery('.room_row:gt(2)').addClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice` instead:

```
jQuery('.room_row').addClass('hide').slice(0,2).removeClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if (jQuery('#target').val() == '2') {
    jQuery('.room_row:lt(2)').removeClass("hide");
  }
```

Comment: Line 3 works if I remove line 2 but your code doesnt remove the hide class from any elements as it is.

Comment: Why would having addCLass followed by removeClass not work? I tried something similar myself earlier and had the same issue. Thanks